# input filtering in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I am working on e-commerce React/Redux project, I want to make functionality by which user can display the products according to price filter, I have made two input fields in which user can type min and max price value and can display the products which lie between the price range,
the functionality is working **onChange** but not displaying the products between the range, it is displaying general products

can anyone help me to sort this issue, Thanks in advance, My code and screenshot is attached below

---

```
class PriceInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: props.values,
        };
        this.onValueChangeComplete = this.onValueChangeComplete.bind(this);
    }

    onValueChangeComplete() {
        const { onValueChange } = this.props;

        onValueChange(this.state.value);
    }


    render() {
        const { currencyCode, limits } = this.props;
        const { value } = this.state;
        const notChanged = _.isEqual(value, limits);

        return (
            <div className={styles.wrapper}>
              <div className={styles.inputWrapper}>
                  {I18n.getComponent(
                      (formattedValue) =>
                          <input
                              type="text"
                              name="min"
                              className={styles.textInput}
                              placeholder={formattedValue}
                          />,
                      'filter.price-range-min'
                  )}
                <span className={styles.between}>{I18n.getText('filter.price-aed', {}, 'To')}</span>
                  {I18n.getComponent(
                      (formattedValue) =>
                          <input
                              type="text"
                              name="max"
                              className={styles.textInput}
                              placeholder={formattedValue}
                              onChange={this.onValueChangeComplete}
                          />,
                      'filter.price-range-min'
                  )}
              </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Component in which I have to used the price functionality**

```
case 'price':
                            childComponent = (
                                <PriceInput values={facet.data}
                                    limits={facet.data}
                                    currencyCode={this.props.currency.code}
                                    onValueChange={(data) => this.onSearchChange(facet.code, data)}/>
                            );
                            break;
```

[image]

Comment: Something looks off. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something.. Your `min` input doesn't seem to have an `onChange` function. And you don't seem to use `this.state.value` as a value in your inputs.  What does `props.values` look like? Is it an object?

Comment: can you please help me how to refactor code according to your knowledge @jonahe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a fix (I don't think) but maybe it can bring you closer to a solution. I made some edits to your code and placed comments where I made changes.

```
class PriceInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            // NOTE: I don't know how props.values looks. maybe this is wrong
            min: props.values.min, 
            max: props.values.max
        };
        this.onValueChangeComplete = this.onValueChangeComplete.bind(this);
    }

    onValueChangeComplete(minOrMax, newValue) {
        const { onValueChange } = this.props;
        this.setState(
          {[minOrMax]: newValue}, // update the property "min" or "max" with the new value
          () => onValueChange(this.state) // when the state change is done, send both min and max to onValueChange 
         ); 
       // onValueChange(this.state.value);
    }


    render() {
            // not sure what "limits" are used for
        // maybe you want to use an input with type="number" and 
        // use the attributes "min" and "max" ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number
        const { currencyCode, limits } = this.props;
        const { min, max } = this.state; // this is new. 
        const notChanged = _.isEqual(value, limits);

        return (
            <div className={styles.wrapper}>
              <div className={styles.inputWrapper}>
                  {I18n.getComponent(
                      (formattedValue) =>
                          <input
                                                            value={ min } // this is new
                              type="text"
                              name="min"
                              className={styles.textInput}
                              placeholder={formattedValue}
                              onChange={ event => this.onValueChangeComplete('min', event.target.value) } // this was missing before
                          />,
                      'filter.price-range-min'
                  )}
                <span className={styles.between}>{I18n.getText('filter.price-aed', {}, 'To')}</span>
                  {I18n.getComponent(
                      (formattedValue) =>
                          <input
                                value={ max } // this is new
                              type="text"
                              name="max"
                              className={styles.textInput}
                              placeholder={formattedValue}
                              onChange={ event => this.onValueChangeComplete('max', event.target.value )}
                          />,
                      'filter.price-range-min'
                  )}
              </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @jonahe, code is working fine but the issue is, the page start filtering the products as soon I types value in min(first input) , i wanted to achieve filtering when user types max value after the min value

Comment: And what should happen if the user starts setting the max value, and then sets the min value? I think it could be confusing for the user. IF you need to limit when the filtering should happen, then maybe an extra button "Apply" or something could be used to trigger `onValueChange(this.state);`

Comment: Sorry, made a lot of edits to that earlier comment. Done now.

Comment: I have added screenshot, hope you can understand what will be the functionality,

Comment: Ok, yeah that makes sense. I made a small change to `onValueChangeComplete` that may be enough.

Comment: Hey bro can you revert back to your previous code, with this code their are 10 errors in console

Comment: Sure, sorry. If this version doesn't work either then uncomment this line `// onValueChange(this.state.value);` .   (But that line really shouldn't be there..)

Comment: Are you sure you just didn't notice the errors before? Because I changed quite a lot of code, so it would almost be weird if it didn't break something.

Comment: (I'm going to bed very soon, so soon I won't be replying until 8-10+ hours from now)

Comment: Now thr code is working fine, but i have to do something about the functionality, which i have told you in the screesshot

Comment: Ok good. Can you try replacing `() => onValueChange(this.state)`   with `() => minOrMax == 'max' && onValueChange(this.state)`  ?  Don't know why it broke before. Maybe I forgot a "{" or something..  This does the same but is less readable.

Comment: Hey @jonahe, can you please answer my question that i have asked recently(today)